# Correct syntax for By.PARTIAL_TEXT_LINK in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, webdriverwait, expected-condition, partiallinktext

How to click using `By.Partial_Text_Link` in a proper way?

There is probably a syntax error, but pycharm doesn't give me a solution.

The searched element is not found, the program stops.
The faulty code looks like this:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value="LogSyS"))).click()
```

How does the syntax have to look like?

This code iswebdriverwa working, but i need WebDriverWait function:

```
driver.find_element(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, value= "LogSys").click()
```

Comment: Did you try `(By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "LogSyS")` instead of `(By.PARTIAL_TEXT_LINK, value="LogSyS")`?

Comment: Ups sorry, my post was wrong, i edit now. I mean offcourse by.partial_link_text

Answer (score 0):

Had there been a syntax error you would have faced a *`TypeError`* which seems isn't the case in hand.

To click using [`By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65692574/7429447) you can use the following optimized syntax:

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.PARTIAL_LINK_TEXT, "LogSyS"))).click()
```

If the desired element is still not located/found and raises a *`TimeoutException`* you may have a to relook at the [locator strategy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver)